# Design API flow using RX Java Operators

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm new to RX-Java and I'm trying to design an API where the flow is as mentioned below :

```
            Make REST call A to load data
                        |
                        |
        data not found? |  data found  
    ------------------------------------    
    |                                  |           
    |                                  |            
    |                                  |
Make REST Call B                  Load DB Data 1     
    |                                  |            
    |                                  |
    |                              _________________________
    |                             |       Parallel         |
    |                             |                        |
    |                             |                        |
    |                  (condition using DB data 1)   (condition using DB data 1)
    |                      Load REST Data C                Load DB Data 2
    |                             |                        |
    |                             |________________________|
    |                                         |
    |                                         |
Build Response                            Build Response
```

Assuming DB methods and service calls returns Observable, need some clarity with the skeleton flow for above using rx Operators ?

I'll share the blocking pseudo code below :

```
Response = REST_Call_1(); // on error throw Exception

if (isResponseValid(response)) { // returns Boolean
    if (responseUnderReview(response)) { // validation func 
        throw Exception;
    } else {
        //db_data_1 and db_data_2 can be parallel
        db_data_1 = Load_DB_Data_1();

        // Load data_3 and data_2 based on db_data_1
        if (is_data_3_required(db_data_1)) {
            data_3 = REST_call_2();
        }
        if (is_data_2_required(db_data_1)) {
            db_data_2 = REST_call_2();
        }
        buildResponse(db_data_1, db_data_2, data_3, Response);
    }
} else {
    Response = REST_Call_3(); // on error throw Exception
    buildResponse(response);
}
```

I'm looking at a complete non-blocking asynchronous approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tassos' answer looks reasonable to me and I don't see any other issues mentioned but

> ```
> // dataSource.getItemDetails(activityId returns List<ItemDetail> and is a blocking call
> // So, I want to run it on a separate IO thread.
> return Observable.from(dataSource.getItemDetails(activityId)).observeOn(Schedulers.io());
> ```

If so, turning a blocking single-element call into an off-thread call can be done as follows:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> yourBlockingCall())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.flatMapIterable(v -> v)
...
```

or

```
Observable.defer(() -> Observable.from(yourBlockingCall()))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
...
```

**Edit**: Based on the diagram, I'd setup the following flow:

```
serviceCallA()
.flatMap(a -> {
    if (dataFound(a)) {
        return dbCall1()
           .flatMap(db1 -> {
               Observable o1 = shouldCallServiceC(db1) 
                    ? serviceCallC() : just(placeholderC);
               Observable o2 = shouldCallDB2(db1) 
                    ? dbCall2() ? just(placeHolderDb2);

               return zip(o1, o2, (c, d) -> createResult(c, d));   
           });
    }
    return serviceCallB()
        .map(c -> mapToResultType(c));
});
```

Comment: 1 minor issue with @tassos solution is that switchIfEmpty expects the Observable type to be same as that of upstream.But in may case; the REST_Call_3() will return a response of different type. How can we resolve this ? Please advice.

Comment: Map everything to an union type (or record type) and then at the very end map it back to the desired result type.

Comment: I followed the same approach except that I need to carry forward upstream data 'a' and 'db1' in this case for use in createResult and hence my 2 observables inside zip returns Pair carrying a total of 4 data required for createResult. Works but makes code look little complicated ! Thanks.

Comment: Something like below : serviceCallA()
.filter(response -> isValidResponse(response))
.flatMap(response -> transformResponse(response))
.flatMap(a ->
 reviewValidation(a)
  ? dbCall1(a)
  : Observable.error(new Exception())
)
.flatMap(data ->
 Observable.zip(
  dbCall2(data.getLeft(), data.getRight()),
  CallServiceC(data.getLeft(), data.getRight()),
  (a,b) -> buildResponse(a, b)
)

Answer (score 4):

The general flow of the logic can be as follows:

```
retrofitClient
.loadData()...
.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()) // or handle specific errors only
.flatMap(foundData -> 
    Observable.zip(
       database.call1(foundData),
       database.call2(foundData),
       (call1, call2) -> buildResponse(call1,call2)
    )
 )
 .switchIfEmpty(() ->
    retrofitClient
    .callB()
    .map(response -> buildResponse(response))
 )
```

Note that if there's complex logic in the flow I always try to extract it into separate methods. In your case, calling the database based on the REST calls might involve some conversions - if the resulting logic is more than a line or two, I'd move it to a separate method and use a method reference in the RX flow.

The idea is to have the flow as something that can be looked at and parsed in a single page, and hide implementation details in methods.

Edit: After your edit, maybe this makes more sense:

```
REST_Call_1()
.filter(response -> isResponseValid(response))
.flatMap(response ->
     isResponseUnderReview(response)
     ? Observable.error(new Exception())
     : Observable.just(response)
)
.flatMap(foundData -> 
    Observable.zip(
       fetchData13(foundData),
       Load_DB_Data_2(foundData),
       (data13, call2) -> buildResponse(data13.getLeft(),call2,data13.getRight())
    )
 )
 .switchIfEmpty(() ->
    REST_Call_3()
    .flatMap(response -> buildResponse(response))
 )
 .subscribe(....)

 private Observable<Pair<DbData1, DbData3>> fetchData13(foundData) {
    return
    Load_DB_Data_1()
    .flatMap(data1 -> is_data_3_required(data1)
        ? REST_call_2().map(data3 -> Pair.of(data1, data3))
        : Pair.of(data1, null));
 }
```

Comment: 1 minor issue with the solution is that switchIfEmpty expects the Observable type to be same as that of upstream.But in may case; the REST_Call_3() will return a response of different type. How can we resolve this ? Please advice.

Comment: If you see my solution, I have a `.map(response -> buildResponse(response))` in there for exactly this reason.

Comment: Done, in your original description you do mention that everything returns Observables, apparently I missed that.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't in the original case. Don't accept this answer; use a flatMap to determine which of the 2 branches to execute (read: return as Observables).